# Template not coming up when I run my Ember Server

Tags: templates, ember.js, handlebars.js, emblem.js

I have created a very simple application template on a newly created Ember app that just has a title of "Casteva" and h1 of "Welcome to Casteva.  It is in my application.emblem file within templates and looks like this:

```
#title Casteva

h1 Welcome to Casteva

== outlet
```

However, whenever I run Ember server, a blank page is the only thing that appears.  Any ideas on why this is?

Comment: Can you link to the repo, or post a link to a JSBin with the same issue? There's no way to know with only that information.

Comment: There is also a problem with my repo that shows an empty folder where my ember app should be.  However, I found out why this is happening and it has turned into a different question.  The problem is that I am not precompiling my templates.  So do you know how to precompile my templates and what the index.html file looks like after you do so? @alexlafroscia

Comment: Can you post a link to your repo?

Comment: https://github.com/EmmonsVentures/casteva @alexlafroscia

Comment: Is that an Ember CLI application? I took a look at it and there seems to be a whole bunch of things that seem "off"; missing a `bower.json` file, the `node_modules` are checking into the repo, you're missing an `ember-cli-build.js` file... If you're not using the Ember CLI, the first step is to stop what you're doing and get set up with that.  If you need help, we can set up some way for you to PM me.

Comment: That is a Node.js application, but the my-app folder is a Ember CLI application.  I'm not sure why I am unable to open to the my-app folder on GitHub though.  You're help would be greatly appreciated.  What would you suggest the next step to be? @alexlafroscia

Comment: Why don't you make an account over at the Ember Community Slack and send me a PM.  My username on there is the same as on here.  You can sign up for an account here: https://ember-community-slackin.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 1):

```
ember install ember-cli-emblem
```